# uninstall application

Tags: release-freya, software-installation

I newbie and have some problem here. I run elementary os freya.
I installing an application through terminal. but, when installing i get some problem. So i'm close the terminal and reinstalling the app. But i cant. The terminal says "the package not fully installed or deleted."
Now i can't install app or update!
How i fix it?
I have search & try the solution from other linux but not working.
I hope you're all can help me and find the solution. Thank you.
(Sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately your question is not clear but I will answer it as per my understanding. I guess you are installing applications with apt-get install command. To fix the issue of "the package not fully installed or deleted." You need to follow these steps.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
```

The 2nd command should install the dependent packages that you missed in earlier installation.

Answer (score 0):

You probably better install Synaptic, which is a graphical package manager and easier to handle than terminal. Some packages are dependent on others. Synaptic has the option to remove and/or fix broken packages and dependencies, so I'd say give it a try and reinstall using Synaptic. You can install Synaptic via Software Center or terminal using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed Synaptic Package Manager, found the application I wanted to remove, and it was simple.  I've used Synaptic for years in other distros, just didn't think of it.